# Finding number of asymptotes in $[ 0 , 2\pi]$ interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Consider $f(x) = \frac{2\tan 2x + 1}{2\cos x + 1}$ . Now find number of asymptotes in $[ 0 , 2\pi]$ interval . I know we can simplify it to $\frac{2\sin 2x + 1}{\cos 2x (2\cos x + 1)}$ and then solve $\cos 2x (2\cos x + 1) = 0$ but is there any way for doing it straightly without simplifying ? Also I'm looking for an instruction in order to finding number of asymptotes .

Comment: You won't need simplification; just find all $x$ where either:1)The numerator has finite value and the denominator is $0$ or 2)The denominator tends to a finite value but the numerator tends to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos2x\neq0$ gives asymptotes $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$,  $x=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$ and $x=\frac{7\pi}{4}$.

$\cos{x}\neq-\frac{1}{2}$ gives asymptotes $x=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and  $x=\frac{4\pi}{3}$.

Id est, we have six asymptotes.

Comment: I think $5\pi / 4$ is missing .

Comment: @S.H.W You are right. I fixed.

Comment: Thank you , Can you give me an instruction for finding asymptotes generally ?

Comment: @S.H.W If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\infty$ then $x=a$ is asymptote. If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=a$ then $y=a$ is asymptote. There are also asymptotes like $y=mx+n$, where $m\neq0$. If you want, i can explain how to find it.

Comment: If it is possible , please explain .

Comment: @S.H.W If there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=m$ and there is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}(f(x)-mx)=n$ then $y=mx+n$ is an asymptote of $f$ for $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Okay , Thank you for the answers .